# SQL group by different values in different fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to make a query in my mySQL DB

I Have

```
Field 1 | Field 2 | url
v1      | Value01 | http:1
v1      | Value02 | http:2
v2      | Value02 | http:3
v3      | Value01 | http:4
v3      | Value02 | http:5
v2      | Value02 | http:6
```

I try to count the values from field 2 when they are repeated
all grouped by Field 1

I expect this

```
Field 1  | count Value01(from Field 2)|count Value02(from Field 2)
v1       | 1                          | 1
v2       | 0                          | 2
v3       | 1                          | 1
```

is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: For your input your desire output shoul be `v1 | 1 | 1 ` because only one `Value01` and one `Value02` for `v1` ?

Comment: Can you give a clearer example? I can't understand what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Yes juan you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a conditional `COUNT` or `SUM`

- You can remove the `ELSE NULL` because is the default return for `CASE` but I include it for clear reading.

.

```
SELECT 
    Field1, 
    COUNT( CASE 
             WHEN Field2 = 'Value01' THEN 1
             ELSE  NULL
           END) as count_Value01,
    SUM  ( CASE 
             WHEN Field2 = 'Value02' THEN 1
             ELSE  0
           END) as count_Value02
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Field1
```

Comment: thanks!
I think is: WHEN Field2 = 'Value01' **then** 1 instead of **=**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using conditional aggregation.  This is particularly simple in MySQL:

```
select field1, sum(field2 = 'Value1') as NumValue01,
       sum(field2 = 'Value02') as NumValue2
from table t
group by field1;
```